# Making two highcharts update one another on hover

Tags: javascript, highcharts, interactive

I recently had this dream to make two charts that interact with one another, using javascript and the Highcharts package - but I have very little knowledge of both. What I've done so far has been a mix of begging ChatGPT to teach me javascript and misusing array functions. I managed to get the basics of the plots going but the mouseover logic to change the chartData dynamically is daunting to me - even with highcharts documentation. Can someone point me in the right direction/last best practices for these kinds of scrips where charts interact with one another?

**Background**

Every day, an amount is bought/sold in a future month.

The first chart is a stacked column chart, where the x axis represents days, and each stack is a future month, with the full column representing the total future amounts that have been bought/sold.

The second chart shows, for a single day, what is the breakout/drilldown of those purchases.
The x-axis represents future months. We can want to show one day at a time here. By default, we show the most recent day's purchases. This is just a column from the first chart broken out.

As you hover on a different day from the first chart, the second chart updates with the future months bought/sold at that time.

As you hover on an individual month from the second chart, the first chart updates to show the history of just that month over time.

It's not so simple to understand the relationship between the two at a glance so I wanted to add some interactivity. This gif illustrates what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: gif displaying interactivity between two charts]

This is where I got with my code. It can generate plots although not too well.

```
// dataset
const chartData = [
  { day: '2/10/2023', delivery: '3/1/2023', value: 10, color: 'dodgerblue' },
  { day: '2/10/2023', delivery: '4/1/2023', value: 3, color: 'gold' },
  { day: '2/10/2023', delivery: '5/1/2023', value: 1, color: 'green' },
  { day: '2/11/2023', delivery: '3/1/2023', value: 7, color: 'dodgerblue' },
  { day: '2/11/2023', delivery: '4/1/2023', value: 3.2, color: 'gold' },
  { day: '2/11/2023', delivery: '5/1/2023', value: 0.8, color: 'green' },
  { day: '2/12/2023', delivery: '3/1/2023', value: -3, color: 'dodgerblue' },
  { day: '2/12/2023', delivery: '4/1/2023', value: 7.5, color: 'gold' },
  { day: '2/12/2023', delivery: '5/1/2023', value: -1, color: 'green' },
  { day: '2/13/2023', delivery: '3/1/2023', value: 4, color: 'dodgerblue' },
  { day: '2/13/2023', delivery: '4/1/2023', value: 2, color: 'gold' },
  { day: '2/13/2023', delivery: '5/1/2023', value: -0.5, color: 'green' },
];


// Create an array of unique delivery values
const days = [...new Set(chartData.map((d) => d.day))];

const this_day = days.at(-1) \\ by default chart2 will be the last day...

// Chart #1
Highcharts.chart('chart1', {
  chart: {type: 'column'},
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      stacking: 'normal',
    }
  },

  title: {text: 'By day'},
  xAxis: {
    categories: days,
    title: {text: 'day'}
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {text: 'Total Value'},
    stackLabels: {enabled: true}
  },
  series: chartData.reduce((acc, data) => {
    const found = acc.find(series => series.name === data.delivery);
    if (found) {
      found.data.push(data.value);
    } else {
      acc.push({
        name: data.delivery,
        data: [data.value],
        color: data.color
      });
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
});

// Chart #2
Highcharts.chart('chart2', {
  chart: {type: 'column'},
  title: {text: 'By Delivery'},
  xAxis: {
    categories: chartData.filter(row => row.day == this_day).map(data => data.delivery),
    title: {text: 'delivery'}
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {text: 'Monthly Value'},
  },
  series: chartData.filter(({ day }) => day === this_day).reduce((acc, data) => {
    const found = acc.find(series => series.name === data.delivery);
    if (found) {
      found.data.push(data.value);
    } else {
      acc.push({
        name: data.delivery,
        data: [data.value],
        color: data.color
      });
    }
    return acc;
  }, []), 
});
```

and the HTML I used in jsfiddle

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<div id="chart1" style="height: 360px; width: 45%;display:inline-block;"></div>
<div id="chart2" style="height: 360px; width: 45%;margin-left:5%;display:inline-block;"></div>
```

Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: I would expect to see some kind of [mouseOver](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.mouseOver) function here if you want something to happen on hover.

Comment: Certainly, also probably something using `.setdata` for the dynamic update but I'm a few weeks away from understanding enough javascript to get this working on my own. Any examples at all would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a parametrized function for creating the second chart's series and call `chart.update` in `mouseOver` event.

```
plotOptions: {
  column: {
    stacking: 'normal',
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          chart2.update({
            series: getDeliverySeries(this.category)
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

For the first chart, it is enough to just show/hide proper series:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function() {
          const point = this;
          chart1.series.forEach(function(s) {
            if (s.index !== point.series.index) {
              s.hide();
            }
          });
        },
        mouseOut: function() {
          chart1.series.forEach(function(s) {
            s.show();
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kejsyow0/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.point.events

Comment: Perfectly answered my question, and thanks for including the example - really helpful.